# Loop through CSS tables and count selected cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to loop through all the css-table and display how many cells are selected in each one.

I am using a each method but it does not seem to work.

Thanks for any help.

My code is below and this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/o56erbt2/)

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.css-table-td').click(function () {
        var theTable = $(this).closest('.css-table');
            $(this).toggleClass("highligh-cell");
    });
});

$("#csstableinfo").click( function() {  
    var sCount=0;
    $(".css-table  div").each(function (index) {       
  //     sCount=theTable.find('.css-table-td.highligh-cell').length;   this is not workikng    
        alert (sCount)
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="css-table">
    <div class="css-table-tr">
        <div class="css-table-td" id="1">b</div>
        <div class="css-table-td" id="2">c</div>
        <div class="css-table-td" id="3">e</div>
       </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="css-table">
    <div class="css-table-tr">
        <div class="css-table-td" id="1">b</div>
        <div class="css-table-td" id="2">c</div>
        <div class="css-table-td" id="3">e</div>
       </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="css-table">
    <div class="css-table-tr">
        <div class="css-table-td" id="1">b</div>
        <div class="css-table-td" id="2">c</div>
        <div class="css-table-td" id="3">e</div>
       </div>
</div>
<br/>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" id="csstableinfo" VALUE="Count Selected">
```

css:

```
.css-table {
    display: table;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.css-table-tr {
    display: table-row;
     height:30px;
}
.css-table-td {
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    width: 30px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.highligh-cell {
    background: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".css-table  .highligh-cell").length` will give you the number of selected elements, no need to use each.

```
$("#csstableinfo").click(function () {
    alert($(".css-table  .highligh-cell").length);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/o56erbt2/4/)

**EDIT:**

To get how many in each table are selected:

```
$("#csstableinfo").click(function () {
    var msg = "";
    $(".css-table").each(function(index) {
        var sCount = $(this).find('.highligh-cell').length;
        msg += "table_" + index + " = " + sCount + "\n";
    });
    alert(msg);
});
```

[**Updated jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/o56erbt2/5/)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know how many cells are selected in each table, not the total selected. My goal is to know if all the cells have the same amount of selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

Are you even getting an alert set? if not, the problem is with the $(".css-table  div") call. You shouldn't call it this way since every div you call already containing the css table class.

try using $(".css-table"), if it's not working, it's better working with id's.

P.S. you are using different classes for each row also, so it won't identify the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to increase the counter and make each for the class of selected i.e `.highligh-cell`:

```
$("#csstableinfo").click( function() {  
    var sCount=0;
    $(".highligh-cell").each(function (index) {       
  //     sCount=theTable.find('.css-table-td.highligh-cell').length; 
        sCount++;

    });
     alert (sCount)
});
```

Checkout [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/o56erbt2/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I guess I was not clear in my post. I am looking to get the total selected for each table that way I can compare them.